# Google Adsense on simple one-page website

Tags: adsense

I've recently created a demo site for my project, I've been getting around 150 +/- visits a week. I wanted to add Google AdSense to the site, I don't expect to make any kind of serious money from this but I really want to get some experience with Google Adsense and it seems very interesting to me.

The site URL is https://uwuifier.com, I've applied for the AdSense program thrice, at the first attempt I added the last block with more text. But I've still been rejected for not having enough content. Now I get that this isn't some website 40 blog posts but I feel like I should still be able to monetize a demo website?

Or perhaps I misunderstood the AdSense program and it's only meant for larger sites with user-generated content?

Comment: Your website aren't adsense target : https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/61242252?hl=en "AdSense means _AdSense for content_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website may be rejected because it's not getting enough traffic, if your website gets enough traffic it should be suited for AdSense. An alternative could be [media.net](https://www.media.net/)